# Python regex for multiple delimiters including double quotes

Tags: python, regex, parsing

Code in python using regex that can perform something like this

**The input:**

```
> https://test.com, 2017-08-14, "This is the title with , and "anything" in it", "This is the paragraph also with , and "anything" in it"
```

**The ideal output:**

```
['https://test.com', '2017-08-14', 'This is the title with , and "anything" in it', 'This is the paragraph also with , and "anything" in it']
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a code or regex writing service. We're glad to help once you've made an effort to solve the problem yourself and run into difficulties. When you do, you can explain the problem you've encountered, include the *relevant* code, and ask a **specific question** about that code, and we can try to help. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

There are several split methods you can use.

The vanilla built-in split method accepts the delimiter as an argument and will do what is written on the tin, split a string exactly at whatever delimiter you've specified, returning it as a list.

In your case, the delimiter you want is a "," but only the commas that are not inside quotation marks. In ordinary cases for something like you could do:

```
foo = 'https://test.com, 2017-08-14, "This is the title with , and "anything" in it", "This is the paragraph also with , and "anything" in it"'


print foo.split(',')
#but this has the caveat that you don't have any ','s within your input as those will become delimitation points as well, which you do not want.
```

In this particular case you could also match for say, ", "
but this would also fail because your input has an element `title with , and "any` and that would be incorrectly split.

Rather in this case, we can use `shlex` and use it's `split` method. Now, this split method will have the delimiter set at whitespace.

So, doing:

```
print [_ for _ in shlex.split(foo)]
```

will give us something closer to what we want, but not exactly:

```
>>> ['https://test.com,', '2017-08-14,', 'This is the title with , and anything in it,', 'This is the paragraph also with , and anything in it']
```

As can be seen, it has the nasty commas in the elements, which we don't want.

Unfortunately, we cannot do

```
print [_[:-1] for _ in shlex.split(foo)]
```

for that will cut off the last 't' in 'it', but we can use string's built in

```
rstrip
```

method

and match for any commas at the end of the each of the elements:

```
print [_.rstrip(',') for _ in shlex.split(foo)]
```

giving the output:

```
>>> ['https://test.com', '2017-08-14', 'This is the title with , and anything in it', 'This is the paragraph also with , and anything in it']
```

which is **very close to** what we want but not exactly! (Missing the **"** around the 'anything' -- shlex gobbles this up!).

But, we're very close and I'll leave that minor tidbit for your homework, which you should try for a solution first as others have posted.

Resources:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_split.htm

https://docs.python.org/2/library/shlex.html

P.S. Hint: look at csv module as well.

Comment: This is not correct. OP doesn't want `,` inside `"` be splited. See The Ideal Output.

Comment: @lincr Oopsies, you're right. It'll split the string at any comma it finds. Thought this was very trivial HW question so I glanced over the input too quickly =p. I updated the code to something a bit closer, but left his hw question for him to actually try and finish. Thanks.